# ValueAnimator doesn't seem to work properly on my phone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do a color transition on my backgound `View` with `ValueAnimtor`, it works well on my emulator, but on my phone, the old color just snap into the new color without smooth transition.

I tried some other ways with ValueAnimtor but it's still the same.

My code:

```
ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
                anim.setIntValues(Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE);
                anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        int a = (Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        Log.e("color", String.valueOf(a));
                        background.setBackgroundColor((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
                    }
                });

                anim.setDuration(3000);
                anim.start();
```

And Here is what Logcat prints:

Emulator:

```
   2021-10-12 12:04:33.897 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.023 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -236
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.157 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -216
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.286 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -197
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.384 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -184
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.512 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.513 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -166
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.513 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.613 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -154
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.614 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -239
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.689 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -145
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.689 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -228
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.775 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -135
    2021-10-12 12:04:34.775 11828-11828/com.deple.isub E/color: -216
      ...
```

On my real device ( OPPO A31, android 9 ):

```
2021-10-12 12:05:37.304 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
2021-10-12 12:05:37.307 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
2021-10-12 12:05:37.308 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
2021-10-12 12:05:37.375 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
2021-10-12 12:05:37.378 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
2021-10-12 12:05:37.391 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
2021-10-12 12:05:37.393 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
2021-10-12 12:05:37.416 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
2021-10-12 12:05:37.418 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
2021-10-12 12:05:37.424 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
2021-10-12 12:05:37.427 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
2021-10-12 12:05:37.436 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -256
2021-10-12 12:05:37.440 3574-3574/com.deple.isub E/color: -1
```